# How to refer to a relative path of a YAML file in a Google App Engine project?

Tags: python, yaml, google-ads-api

I need to load in a YAML file to use the Adwords API. So far I've been referring to the absolute path of that file:

```
adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage("/Users/MyUserName/MyProject/googleads.yaml")
```

This works fine locally but it won't once in production. How can I refer to a relative path in App engine? Should I use a solution with the `sys` or `os` library? Or can I import the yaml file some different easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If yaml file is in the same directory as your python file:

import os

```
yaml_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'googleads.yaml')
```